# How to import SQLite Database from disk file in memory when using laravel?

Tags: sqlite, laravel

I am using in memory SQLite datase with my Laravel app for testing.

```
'database' => ':memory:'
```

What I need is before running tests - import some specific data from already existing SQLite database file(can't use seeder, because there is too much data already). 
How can I import data from disk file to in-memory before running tests?

Comment: You can't, at least not with PHP, because the [Backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) that you need to do this is not available for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

No need to keep i in memory, if you have the database on disk.

When you first read the database from disk, it will end up in your disk cache your OS keep for you. So in reality the database will reside in memory, when you read it once.

Comment: Could you please provide some reference (from the documentation or source code perhaps) that showcases how **the entire database** is loaded into memory, because this sounds like a highly unlikely approach from a performance standpoint (especially if the database is very large). To my knowledge there is page caching involved when reading a database but it's limited by configuration values and setting large values for that might not be a good approach from a configuration standpoint.

Comment: The database is not very large to begin with, if it is supposed to be a memory-database. 

And since it is Sqlite-database, it is not very large either.